# C# Winforms - setting combobox selected value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I want to set name and value pairs for combobox. So I created a class named `Item` like this:

```
// Content item for the combo box
private class Item
{
    private readonly string Name;
    private readonly int Value;
    private Item(string _name, int _value)
    {
        Name = _name; Value = _value;
    }
    private override string ToString()
    {
        // Generates the text shown in the combo box
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And data set like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
// For example get from database continentals.
var gets = _connection.Continentals;
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item("--- Select a continental. ---", 0));
foreach (var get in gets)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item(get.name.Length > 40 ? get.name.Substring(0, 37) + "..." : get.name, Convert.ToInt32(get.id)));
}
// It points Africa.
comboBox1.SelectedValue = 3;
```

Here is the output:

```
// 1 - Europe
// 2 - Asia
// 3 - Africa
// 4 - North America
// 5 - South America
// 6 - Australia
// 7 - Antartica
```

In my example The Africa continental must be selected but it is not.
And more than that in my edit form, for example this code gets datas from `person` table:

`var a = _connection.persons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == Id);`

When I code `comboBox2.SelectedValue = a.continental`, the Africa continental must be selected, but it is not. I did not solve the problem.

Comment: I think you need SelectedIndex=3 or SelectedIndex=IndexOf().

Comment: SelectedItem, Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property documentation:

> **Property Value**
>   An object containing the value of the member of the data source specified by the [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
>
> **Remarks**
>   If a property is not specified in [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx), SelectedValue returns the results of the **ToString** method of the object.

To get the desired behavior, you need to expose `Name` and `Value` as public properties of your `Item` class and utilize the `DataSource`, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties of the control:

```
// Content item for the combo box
private class Item
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    private Item(string _name, int _value)
    {
        Name = _name; Value = _value;
    }
}
```

and the sample usage:

```
// Build a list with items
var items = new List<Item>();
// For example get from database continentals.
var gets = _connection.Continentals;
items.Add(new Item("--- Select a continental. ---", 0));
foreach (var get in gets)
{
    items.Add(new Item(get.name.Length > 40 ? get.name.Substring(0, 37) + "..." : get.name, Convert.ToInt32(get.id)));
}
// Bind combobox list to the items
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; // will display Name property
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"; // will select Value property
comboBox1.DataSource = item; // assign list (will populate comboBox1.Items)

// Will select Africa
comboBox1.SelectedValue = 3;
```

Comment: I know, this textbox is for asking more information, but thank you very much for your help.