# is it possible to use a variable as identifier of a class member

Tags: c#, winforms, class, identifier

I am working on a windows forms project
and i have a Person Class like this (simplified):

```
    class Person
    { public string name;
      public int age;

         public Person(string nameInput,int ageInput)
         {
            name=nameInput;
            age = ageInput;
         }
     }
```

now i wanna initiate some members of the class but i wanna use an Input as the Identifier of the member like this:

```
Person someTextBox.Text = new Person(name.Text,age.Text);
```

Because i cant know how many Persons the user wants to make and i cant know how he wants to call them i cant just do somethink like

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
Person p3 = new Person();
...
```

the identifier is important cause i wanna make a dropdown where the user can select his declared Persons and get the information like age shown

Problem is it doesn´t recognize "someTextBox.Text" as a variable but a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not possible to dynamically change how many local variables or fields a method or class has. But it sounds like you could use a collection of some sort, like a dictionary with the string from `someTextBox.Text` as the key and a `Person` object as the value.

Comment: What does the line `Person someTextBox.Text = new Person(name.Text,age.Text);` mean of supposed to mean?

Comment: So you want a reference to a specific `Person` to be held by the control along with some text you provide?

Comment: its supposed to be the constructor of my "Person" class using "someTexBox.Text" as identifier. is there something wrong about it?

Comment: Constructors cannot return values; so yes there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Basically yes, but i want a Person and some Variables conected to the Person.

Comment: The `new` returns a reference to the newly created object. By assigning that reference to say an `object` at minimum or a `Person` at best one has a reference (or an internal address) to the object. Maybe an explanation of what you want to do with this *variable identifier* might help us give you a solution.

Comment: I want to create a Person e.g. named Bob and assign some Information related to him like his lastname his adress and his Job. after that i want to select Bob in my dropdown menu and get the Information displayed in some Textboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By overriding the `ToString()` on the `Person` class you can return a specific attribute about the `Person` in question such as full name:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{First} {Last}";
}
```

So when one sets the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` it uses `ToString`, *since we didn't directly specify a `DisplayMember` to use as the viewable strings in the drop down*.

Here I am loading a `ComboBox`:

```
public List<Person> People { get; set; }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    People = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {First = "Frank", Last = "Wright"},
        new Person() {First = "Omega", Last = "Man"}
    };

    cbPeople.DataSource = people;
}
```

So when I launch the page I see this:

[image]

---

Here is my full `Person` class

```
public class Person
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{First} {Last}";
    }

}
```

---

**How to Retrieve Selected**

Note to be clear on what the `ComboBox` has as the user selected item, it stores a reference to the `People` item and returns it in `SelectedItem` or via a number in `SelectedIndex`. So if I wanted the current selected item in the last example I would do this:

```
var mySelectedPerson = cbPeople.SelectedItem;

var name = mySelectedPerson.ToString(); // "Frank Wright"
```

Comment: Otherwise if I didn't answer your question, you might want to get to know the `SelectedValue`. Here is a SO question [C# Winforms - setting combobox selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944146/c-sharp-winforms-setting-combobox-selected-value) that might be related to your end goal.

Comment: Sorry for answering this delayed, i was busy in rl. Anyways i decided i wont use a class or something but save the variables in a folder on my harddrive, cause i think its easier to code (atleast i know how to do this) and i can save it permanently this way easier. Sorry for the inconvenience and my bad english, im just beginning to code and im not a native speaker.

Comment: Sounds good Leon. GL and posting to SO helps with both English and programming. :-)